# replace matches in NSString with template using NSRegularExpression

Tags: objective-c, regex

I'm trying to detect `<br>` or `<Br>` or `< br>`,... in NSString and replace it with `\n`.
I use `NSRegularExpression` and i wrote this code:

```
NSString *string = @"123 < br><br>1245; Ross <Br>Test 12<br>";
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<[* ](br|BR|bR|Br|br)>" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) withTemplate:@"\n"];


NSLog(@"%@", modifiedString);
```

it works fine but it replace first matching only, not replacing all matches. Please help me to detect all matches and replace them.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, you need to have it handle any number of spaces after your initial `<`, and handle if it doesn't have any space at all.

Using your [example](http://rubular.com/r/mYLG0C5CVV), you can use the regex `<\s*(br|BR|bR|Br|br)>` to have it accept the `0 to N` spaces before your BR works.  You can also simplify it a little bit more by making it case insensitive with `i`, which allows for a cleaner looking regex to handle all the variations on `BR` you will see.  [To do that](http://rubular.com/r/99EWNZnWDY), use `(?i)<\s*br>`.

I think for completeness you can also include an arbitrary amount of space AFTER the `br`, just to handle anything that could be thrown.  I agree with adding in some sort of catch for a `/>` to end the pattern, since `<br/>` is valid HTML as well.  It makes the regex look a little more [crazy](http://rubular.com/r/SqxhLInAh4), but it boils down to just adding the other 3 pieces.

`(?i)<\s*br\s*\/?\s*>`

It looks really scary, but breaks down very simply into a few parts:

1. `(?i)` turns on case insensitive to handle the variations on the `br`.
2. `<\s*` is the start of the tag directly followed by an arbitrary number of spaces.
3. `br\s*` is your `br` chars followed by an arbitrary number of spaces.
4. `\/?` is to handle 0 or 1 instances of the closing slash (to handle HTML valid tags like `<br/>` and `<br>`.
5. `\s*>` is handling an arbitrary number of spaces and then the closing `>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Walls , Regex `(?i)<\s*br>` works like a charm!!

Comment: @Hossam I agree with David's inclusion of the `/` handling at the end, so I have added that in, as well as a breakdown of the regex into smaller pieces to help you out in the future.  Regex can be scary at first, but breaking it down little by little makes it a whole lot easier to learn at first.

Answer (score 2):

You currently don't handle an arbitrary amount of white space. For good measure you should also handle white space after `br` and also handle the closing slash since `<br />`  is the correct way of writing the line break in HTML.

You would end up with an pattern that looks like this

```
<\s*(br|BR|bR|Br|br)\s*\/*>
```

or written as a NSRegularExpression

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = 
  [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<\\s*(br|BR|bR|Br|br)\\s*\\/*>" 
                                            options:0 
                                              error:&error];
```

#### Edit

You could also make the pattern more compact by separating the two letters

```
<\s*([bB][rR])\s*\/*>
```

Comment: Thanks for mention the <br/> case for me, i added it to my regex